# How can i get the rotación of a node from the JSON document in Figma?

Tags: figma-api

I'm using Figma API to get a figma document but I can not get the rotation of a node. How is the rotation of an object calculated?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Figma plugin API, you can just access `rotation` property. See the documentation [here](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/nodes-rotation/).

If you are using the Figma REST API, you can get it from the `relativeTransform` property. Given a transform value of `[[m00, m01, m02], [m10, m11, m12]]`, I believe the rotation should be `atan2(-m10, m00)`. This ends up being the angle of the x axis of the transform. Note that `relativeTransform` is only present if you pass `geometry=paths`. See the documentation [here](https://www.figma.com/developers/api) for more information.